# Inserting Scope identity into second table using Entity Framework and dynamic Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework-4, webmethod

I have two tables as follows
1)  Customers

```
customerId  Int (primary key)
customerName    Varchar(50)
Age Int
```

2)  CustomerLoan

```
Id  Int 
customerId  Int (Foreign key)
customerName    Varchar(50)
Age Int
Loan    float
```

From my jquery I am getting multiple records in the form of dynamic json object in the webservice webmethod as shown below (InsertData). 
By using IList and Entity framework I am inserting multiple records.

My requirement here is while inserting customers record, I want to inert few fields from customer table and extra fields in customerloan table.

Bottom line I want to insert cutomerId generated from customer table with few more fields in CustomerLoan table.

Ex:Customer

```
customerId  customerName    Age
100 John    32
101 Jacob   35
```

Ex: CustomerLoan

```
Id  customerId  customerName    Age Loan
1   100 John    32  1500
2   101 Jacob   35  2000



[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public dynamic InsertData(int revision, int appID, dynamic jsonMaster)
{
    dynamic json = jsonMaster;

    IList<Customer> customers = ((object[])json).Select(t => new Customer
    {
        customerId = Convert.ToInt32((((IDictionary)t)["customerId"]) ?? -1),            
        customerName = ((((IDictionary)t)["customerName"]) ?? "").ToString(),
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(((IDictionary)t)["Age"]), 
        Revision = Convert.ToInt32((((IDictionary)t)["Revision"])),            
    }).ToList(); ;


    lock (_updatePointsLock)
    {
        using (CustomerEntities context = new CustomerEntities())
        {
            int currentRevision = context.Customer.Max(x => x.Revision) ?? 0;
            if (currentRevision >= revision)
            {
                foreach (Customer cobj in customers)
                {
                    Customer obj = context.Customer.Where(x => x.customerId == cobj.salesMasterId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (obj == null)
                    {
                        cobj.Revision = currentRevision + 1;                            
                        context.Customer.Add(cobj); 

            **CustomerLoan objLoan = new CustomerLoan();
            objLoan.customerId = cobj.customerId;  
            objLoan.customerName = cobj.customerName;
            objLoan.Age = cobj.Age;
            objLoan.customerLoan = 1500;
            context.CustomerLoan.Add(objLoan);**




                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj.customerName = cobj.customerName;
                        obj.Age = cobj.Age;                            
                        obj.Revision = currentRevision + 1;                          

                    }
                }
                context.SaveChanges();

                return new
                {
                    Revision = currentRevision + 1,
                    Customer = context.Customer.Where(x => x.Revision > revision).Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.customerId,
                        x.customerName,
                        x.Age,                            
                        Revision = x.Revision,                            
                    }).ToList()
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new { Revision = revision };
            }
        }
    }
```

}

With the above code (-1) value inserting in customerId field in customerLoan table.
If create objects to insert outside the foreach values of Customers not getting.
If someone can help inserting identity value customer table in customerLoan highly appreciated.

Comment: When customer not found and new inserted the auto incteemented primary key customerid is not set until you call SaveChanges, so it can’t be used for foreign key, yet..

Answer (score 0):

First save your customer object to database with context.SaveChanges();
Then try to add Customer loan (now you should be able to find the customer Id) and save again to database with context.SaveChanges();

It may have other ways to do it but this is the way I know.

Comment: If I add first customer object to database with context.saveChanges();
I am not getting instance objects of customer (objLoan.customerId = cobj.customerId;) for customer loan.